# commands in indirect variables bash

Tags: bash

My code below doesn't work. 
I am trying to simply save commands to a variable with indirect variable.

After executing I get:

```
*destL="/media/user/something" _destL=destL

rsync_home="rsync -avz --delete /home/ \$$_destL$home"

eval echo `$rsync_home`*
```

Output of this is :

```
*rsync: mkdir "/home/user/place where my script is located/$destL/home" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674) [Receiver=3.1.0]
sending incremental file list*
```

But when I tried to check what is in `*$rsync_home*` with command
`eval echo "$rsync_home"`

Output is correct command:

```
rsync -avz --delete /home/ /media/michal/something/home/
```

Why this indirect variable is not shown in variable as it should, but as `$destL` ?

Comment: Output correct???? See the `.../home/ /media ...`.

Comment: Maybe try using the newer syntax for your variable `${!_destL}`...

Comment: Does the command work if you run it by hand?

Comment: I'L'I, with use of newer syntax, error as : ./backup.sh: Bad substitution

Comment: Ignacio, yes, by hand command works...

Comment: FDavidov, this ..../home/ /media.. these are two directories that should be sync

Comment: @snyco: what is the value of `$home` supposed to be?

Comment: @I'L'I: `$home` contains only `/home/` , so the `$rsync_home` should contains `rsync -avz --delete /home/ /media/michal/something/home/` where /media/michal/something should be taken from indirect variable, but for some reason, it does not want to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using `eval`, and define a function:

```
rsync_home () {
  rsync -avz -delete /home "$1"/home
}
```

Then call

```
rsync_home /media/user/something
```